# nvidia-settings complex problem

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

I have fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 and using it only in ssh.  I have several nvidia gpu on board.

That is the way how i installed drivers (found info in google):

--------------------------DRIVERS INSTALL--------------------------

Preparing:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libc6:i386
```

Disable the default Nouveau NVIDIA driver

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
```

Update kernal initramfs

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Downloaded latest driver https://www.geforce.com/drivers

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.83.run
sudo reboot
```

After that checked by

```
sudo lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 18

08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] [10de:1b06] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device [19da:1471]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 140
        Memory at d4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 2f60000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at 2f70000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 9000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at d5000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

...

--------------------------END DRIVERS INSTALL--------------------------

After that gpus work fine with driver. But

```
 nvidia-settings
** (nvidia-settings:2285): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-G3kXDTdi54: Connection refused
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

First warning solved with help of *export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1*

About *ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system* , i found that i need

```
sudo prime-select nvidia

Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', None]
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled
```

And now i don't know how to solve all this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSH to use nvidia-settings you should use:
(set fan for example)

```
DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1

DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=75
```